# What's wrong with writing to a global variable In production mode?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I looked at the sample code for connecting mongodb and saw a sentence that I did not understand.

Why is it safe to use global variables in the case of development ?
And why is not in production ?

***You don't need to understand the code. Please see only the comments section.***

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

let client
let clientPromise

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  // In development mode, use a global variable so that the value
  // is preserved across module reloads caused by HMR (Hot Module Replacement).
  if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options)
    global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect()
  }
  clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise
} else {
  // In production mode, it's best to not use a global variable.
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options)
  clientPromise = client.connect()
}

// Export a module-scoped MongoClient promise. By doing this in a
// separate module, the client can be shared across functions.
export default clientPromise
```

If this was just about good quality code, it would be better not to use global variables in the development environment as well.

I'm not sure what's wrong with writing to a global variable In production env.

Comment: Isn't it explained in the comments for your code?

Comment: @Pointy 
I read your comment and read the comments carefully once again.
That is, is this what you mean?
In the original case, the variables recorded in the top-level scope are safe, but
It can be erased by hot reloading.
So, in the devlopement environment, we have to save it in the global object.
Then HMR will preserve this. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: It has to do with using "Hot Module Replacement" in development for improving development productivity.  Not something you would do in a production environment.  In hot module replacement, module-level variables like `client` and `clientPromise` would get replaced, but globals would not.  It's a development "trick", not something to do in production.  Personally, I wouldn't even do it in development either because I'd rather be running code that is as close to production as possible when in development except for things that must be different.

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh i see!!!  I think i get!

Comment: For what it's worth I 100% agree with @jfriend00, it's inviting bizarre bugs to explicitly make production and development do things differently in important ways like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with using "Hot Module Replacement" in development for improving development productivity. Not something you would do in a production environment.

In hot module replacement, module-level variables like `client` and `clientPromise` would get replaced when the module was "hot replaced", but globals would be preserved.

It's a development "trick", not something to do in production.

Personally, I wouldn't even do it in development either because I'd rather be running code that is as close to production as possible when in development except for things that must be different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, was looking for this.
from what I understood: 
In Production HMR is turned off, so this tweak gets you closer to production behaviour?