# Preserving Value Across HMR With Global Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, global-variables

When looking at the [NextJS MongoDB Starter](https://github.com/vercel/mongodb-starter), I noticed this bit of code:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  // In development mode, use a global variable so that the value
  // is preserved across module reloads caused by HMR (Hot Module Replacement).
  global._mongoClientPromise = this.clientPromise;
}
```

Here is a link to [the file I am talking about](https://github.com/vercel/mongodb-starter/blob/main/lib/mongodb.ts).

Now, I know of the global object, but what I do not understand is how merely assigning a value to it preserves it, since `global._mongoClientPromise` is never accessed thereafter. In fact, this is the only line in the entire project where this property is used. Maybe it is obvious to some, but I am not a JavaScript expert, so can somebody please explain this to me?

Comment: The pattern as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72581014/1048572) makes more sense

Comment: Looks like [around a month ago this bug was introduced](https://github.com/vercel/mongodb-starter/commit/e2832d58224b291b0b07d4d85ca2e0e24c92e2f9). You're right, it doesn't make sense. You may want to report it.

Comment: Tbh [this whole `class Singleton`](https://github.com/vercel/mongodb-starter/pull/26/files#diff-e41afa6b8b89098cd77976fd5e32614088744fc42693dc4bc66ef971cc7a5f37) does not make much sense

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! The older version you linked, which assigns and also accesses the value, I can understand. But I have another question concerning your last comment: I understand that some see the Singleton pattern as an anti-pattern, but I understand why it is used here. You would not want to open a new connection every time the exported value is accessed. So do you only mean that this could be achieved in a different way, or what is your problem with this?

Comment: No, the global state is fine since that's exactly what is required here, what does not make sense is the use of a `class` here. The `class` is never instantiated, has only `static` methods/fields, is not exported, has a weird name, and used only once - it just doesn't make sense. A simple module-scoped variable would have sufficed.